# Where is this number coming from?

Tags: complex-numbers, logarithms

I am trying to solve $2^x = 3^x$ for $x$.

Now I plug this into WolframAlpha and the steps to the solution are the following:

- Take natural log of both sides which leaves me with this (according to them):

$$ x\ln(2)= x\ln(3) + 2in\pi $$

What I don't understand is where is this $2in\pi$ coming from?

Thank you very much for your time and help.

Comment: $e^{x\ln (2)}=e^{x\ln (3)+2in\pi}$ and now consider what $e^{i\theta}$ represents.

Comment: wouldn't be easier to divide both sides by $3^x$ and conclude that $x=0$ is the only solution in real numbers? WolframAlpha gives you complex solutions

Comment: The user did tag this question as complex-numbers.

Comment: Which may very well come from the fact that Wolfram Alpha gave complex numbers as results to the OP.

Answer (score 4):

It results from:

- rewriting your equation as $e^{xln2} = e^{xln3}*1$
- the property $1 = e^{i2n\pi}$ of complex exponentials (see https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Euler%27s_formula)